# Battery Status problem

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I recently updated my Note 8.0 Wifi from 4.1.2 to android 4.4.2, and shortly after that rooted it (But kept the stock 4.4.2, NO custom ROMs or anything...). Of course, as I knew, the battery consumption was probably going to be a bit higher that 4.1.2... and it was.

But one day i left my tablet to charge for a while (around an hour and a half) and hoped that it will charge from 25% to 100% for that time. But when woke the screen what I saw was not normal... the battery had charged only to 60%. I was worried, as I thought that it might be a battery problem, but then I turned off the device (my mom recommended me to do so) and it showed that big green battery indicator at 100%.

I was relieved, as I thought that it might be just a one time problem, and as I rebooted the device it showed 100% again. But my worries didn't end there, as this problem has now occurred at least 5-6 times.

Is it a battery problem, or a battery indication problem, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to calibrate your battery.

Go to **Play Store** and install **Battery Calibration** from **NèMa**.

Then follow in app instructions to calibrate your battery....  :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link I provided, this should rectify your problem. It will explain in great detail how to to wipe the battery stats in recovery, there are 6 methods shown. Since your are rooted this will do the operation properly.

*http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1821870*

Wipe The Battery deletes the file "batterystats.bin" which is established among / data / system / .... This file contains all the information "vital" and essential for your battery such as charging the maximum and minimum voltage, the charging time and other info ... this file after it was deleted by this procedure, will be recreated by the system properly.